# My css animation and JQuery are not syncing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-animations

I'm building a simple blinking div, it blinks every 3s:

```
.timer { opacity: 1; animation: blink 3s alternate infinite; }

@keyframes blink { to {opacity: .25;} }
```

and it's text content is updated every 3s as well, counting down from 50 to 0:

```
var number = 50;

window.setInterval(function countdown(){ $('.timer').text(number--); }, 3000);
```

However for some reason my animation and JQ slowly become out of sync, you'll notice it after a few animations have run through. I'm wondering how I could go about assuring that they keep in time with each other.

JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rourkemclaren/61ry4s1j/3/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to the CSS `alternate` flag. If you remove it the effect becomes [more streamlined](https://jsfiddle.net/7kue22o6/).

Note that you can also [listen to the CSS animation events using JavaScript](https://jsfiddle.net/5j1gj0fj/) instead of using the `setInterval`:

```
$('.timer').on('animationiteration', function() {
    $(this).text(--number);
});
```